# MySQL Workbench - store a query to apply to various schemas

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We have multiple identical schemas. How can I store a query and easily apply it to any of multiple schemas? Bonus points for a drag & drop or point & click method of executing the query.

My first attempt was to set a variable for the schema, like this

```
SET @db = MySchema;

SELECT * from @db.mytable;
```

but I get `Error Code: 1146. Table 'db.tagdescriptions' doesn't exist`.

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3, connecting to MySQL Community Server (GPL) 5.6.19-log on Win64.

Comment: What version of MySQL and MySQL Workbench are you using? Those details will be quite helpful to people wanting to answer your question. =)

Comment: @Kassandry, I added the info to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Rick wrote:

If you just wanna have an ad hoc solution (not something you frequently use) you could also just have your query in the editor without a schema and sequentially make each of the schemas you want to process the default schema by double clicking on it's name in the schema tree. I.e. make first one default, run the query. Make the next one default and run the query, and so on.

Comment: This suits my purposes well enough. I just waited a bit before accepting to see if anyone proposed something about as easy but less ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Write a "Stored Procedure".  Pass in the database name.  Inside the SP, use CONCAT to build the `SELECT`, PREPARE, EXECUTE to run the `SELECT`, and DEALLOCATE to clean up.

Plan B:

```
USE MySchema;
SELECT * from mytable;
```

Comment: (A) stored procedure - isn't that necessarily server-side? I want client side. (B) `USE` statement - I tried this in a query window, and it returns 0 rows; whereas `SELECT * from MySchema.mytable;` returns all expected results.

Comment: Yes the SP is server-side.  I should have said `USE MySchema; CALL...;` (on client side).

Comment: Is `CALL` used for executing stored procedures? I'm looking for a client-side only approach.

Comment: The construct the SQL in the client (PHP, Java, VB, whatever) and execute it.

Comment: Only trivial SQL applications can be performed without the aid of some client language; you have reached that threshold (I think).